# How do I chain useQuery and useMutation in GraphQL properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, react-hooks

I have useQuery and useMutation from react-apollo-hooks back to back.  I want to be able to use the returned values from useQuery as variables for useMutation.  Currently, the values from useQuery isn't returned in time for the variables, causing the variables to be undefined.

```
const { data, error, loading } = useQuery(GET_POSTS, { 
    variables: {
        id: props.match.params.id
    }
})
const item = props.match.params.id
const owner = data.posts[0].author.id
const variables = { item , owner, startDate, endDate }
const bookItem = useMutation(CREATE_BOOKING_MUTATION, variables)
```

The variable `data.posts[0].author.id` shows undefined. How do I make sure that the returned value is defined in time?

Comment: If you can query that data from the back-end wouldn't you already have that data to use in the resolver for the mutation?

Comment: react suckz.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How do I make sure that the returned value is defined in time?

<del>You can simply check condition after `useQuery` block</del>

---

## UPDATE

**Hooks can't be called conditionally.**

Usual advice is to place condition in `useEffect`:

```
const { data, error, loading } = useQuery(GET_POSTS, { 
  variables: {
    id: props.match.params.id
  }
})
const item = props.match.params.id

// data.posts can be undefined at start
const owner = loading ? null : data.posts[0].author.id
const variables = { item , owner, startDate, endDate }
const bookItem = useMutation(CREATE_BOOKING_MUTATION, variables)
useEffect(() => {
  if(!loading) {
    bookItem(); // called when data ready
  }
})
```

Another option: `useApolloClient`:

- `useQuery` to load data needed in mutation
- `const client = useApolloClient();`
- `useEffect` - conditionally (`!loading` or `data` not empty) use `client.mutate()` with fetched (in query) data as variables;

Custom hook can be done with 3 parameters: `(query, mutation, { mapDataToVariables })`

Comment: the only problem is if I were to place Hooks after if statement, I get error messages like "React Hook "useMutation" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render"

Answer (score 0):

useMutation when the useQuery is completed like this:

```
const bookItem = useMutation(CREATE_BOOKING_MUTATION,{
variables:{//your variables},
// to refrech your query after you create mutation
refetchQueries: [
    {
      query: GET_POSTS,
      awaitRefetchQueries: true,
    },
  ]} );   
const { data, error, loading } = useQuery(GET_POSTS, { 
 variables: {
   id: props.match.params.id
  },
    //useMutation when the useQuery is completed
   onCompleted: () => {
   bookItem();
},
```

})

Answer (score -1):

I think you can pass the variables when you actually call the mutation instead, something like:

```
...
const bookItem = useMutation(CREATE_BOOKING_MUTATION)
...
if(!loading && !error && data) {
  bookItem({
    variables: {
      owner: data.posts[0].author.id,
      ...
    }
  })
}
```