# How to use graphql enum obtained from useQuery in react js for form competion?

Tags: reactjs, enums, graphql, apollo

I an using React, apollo graphql. I am trying to add doctor's designation in the form through graphql enum using introspection query.

I have a graphql enum type that represents doctor's designation and I am using **useQuery** to display it. What I want to do is to use the enum data obtained from this **useQuery** into the form (in the component AddDoctor). But I am always getting null (data undefined) error "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null**".

Here are my snippets:

Enum type

```
enum DesignationType{
 Podiatrist
 GeneralPractitioner
 Pediatrician
 Endocrinologist
}
```

addGQL.js

```
export const ADD_DOCTOR_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation addDoctors($name: String!, $designation:DesignationType! ) {
    addDoctors(
        name: $name,        
        designation: $designation
    ) {
        _id
        name
        designation
        
    }
  }
`
```

AddDoctor.js

```
const AddDoctor = () => {
const DESIGNATION_QUERY = gql`
    query GetEnum {
        __type(name: "DesignationType") {
            enumValues {
                name
            }
        }
    }
`
const {  data, loading } = useQuery(DESIGNATION_QUERY);
const enumValues = loading ? null : data.__type.enumValues;


const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
    name: '',
    designation: ''
    
});

const [addDoctors] = useMutation(ADD_DOCTOR_MUTATION,{
    variables:{
        name: formState.name,
        designation: enumValues       
    }
});
   
return (
    <form 
        onSubmit = {async (e)=>{
            e.preventDefault();
            await addDoctors();

        }}>
       <div> 
        <label> Name: </label>
        <input type ='text' 
               value = {formState.name} 
               onChange={(e)=>
                setFormState({
                    ...formState,
                    name: e.target.value
                })
               }
               placeholder = 'name'/>
       </div>
             
       

       <div> 
        <label>Designation: </label>            
        <select>
            {enumValues.map(enumValue => (
                <option value={enumValue.name}>{enumValue.name}</option>
            ))}   
        </select>
              
       </div>

        <button type = "submit">Add Doctor</button>
    </form>
    
)
```

}

I tried to use `useEffect` too like in this link [How do I chain useQuery and useMutation in GraphQL properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56204854/how-do-i-chain-usequery-and-usemutation-in-graphql-properly), but I couldn't figure out to use the useEffect correctly.
Could anyone please let me know, how could I use the enum value to be used in the form to add the designation ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: `const enumValues = loading ? [] :` ? show query network response

Comment: {"data":{"__type":{"enumValues":[{"name":"Podiatrist","__typename":"__EnumValue"},{"name":"GeneralPractitioner","__typename":"__EnumValue"},{"name":"Pediatrician","__typename":"__EnumValue"},{"name":"Endocrinologist","__typename":"__EnumValue"},{"name":"Neurologist","__typename":"__EnumValue"},{"name":"Rheumatologist","__typename":"__EnumValue"},{"name":"Psychiatrist","__typename":"__EnumValue"},{"name":"Oncologist","__typename":"__EnumValue"}],"__typename":"__Type"}}}

Comment: The above is  being displayed in network's response

Comment: don't render entire form until data ?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand. could you please show it in the form of code?

Comment: `if (loading) return "loading"` before 'main' return (as in docs)

Comment: Thanks a lot man ! It worked out !...I will accept the answer... But could you please pass me any link so that i could learn why this behavior happened?

Comment: "react reconciliation" ... you should use 'key' props at least for divs ... maybe `<select key={enumValues.length}>` would work? (or add it to parent div or even form) .... in short: rendered components tree with data should explicitely differ from earlier one (rendered without data) ... to be properly updated and forced to rerender

Comment: got it, thanks a lot !